# Win32 : How to identify, which field in DATETIME picker control has focus?

Tags: c, winapi, datetimepicker

I have a DATETIMEPICK control inside my Win32 based application with dd/MM/yy format in my application. When inside the control, if current focus for editing is at field "dd" and user press right arrow key (->) it will change focus to "MM" field for editing month. if press right arrow key again it will focus to "yy" field. if user press right arrow key again when the control is focused on last field(yy), nothing will happen.

I want to override this behavior in such a way that when user press arrow key from last field (yy), the control will go out of DATETIMEPICK control and focus to the next control element in that window. For this purpose, I have overload DATETIMEPICK class and trying to override behavior when **VK_RIGHT** event occur.

I am unable to identify which field (dd, MM or yy) in DATETIMEPICK control has focus now. Is there anyway I can know if the highlighted field is "yy"?

Comment: TAB navigates between controls

Comment: TAB and ENTER keys are both overloaded to step out of the control. Now also want to do that same with arrow keys

Comment: No, don't do that. ENTER is for accepting the dialog. Don't use it for control navigation.

Comment: Well other edit control element move to next control element when press enter. so client want the same with edit control. No choice

Comment: Of course you have a choice. You can show the client the platform UX guidelines. ENTER is used to accept a dialog, or complete entry in an in-place edit. It should not be used for navigation. Anyway, I doubt that the control offers the information that you want.

Comment: For my case, enter will validate date field. if correct will move to next field. Thank you for your suggestions :)

Comment: ...as an aside, by "complete entry in an in-place edit" do you mean that behavior on other platforms where pressing Enter in a standard single-line entry control selects all the text but doesn't leave focus? As for the question, I don't think the API allows this; sorry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed `ENTER ... should not be used for navigation`. Yet, and not to argue UX guidelines, but it *is* used for navigation in Excel and others. Users who spend the day with such spreadsheets come to *expect* `ENTER` to *navigate*, and they are usually not of the type to take "*relearn better UX*" for an answer.

Comment: @dvix A spreadsheet is quite special. I think the special nav used by spreadsheets is reasonable.

Comment: DTP is a pretty troublesome control.  No, you cannot easily find out what part of the date has the "focus".